# MDI Title Bar (sometimes) not painted after restore

Tags: winforms, mdi

I'm having a very frustrating issue with WinForms MDI and hope somebody can help me.

Say I have two forms, FormA and FormB. I add both as children to my MDI, then maximize FormA. Then I use the Windows menu on the main MDI to switch to FormB (which is then maximized).

Now the (fun?) part: I restore FormB using the MDI title bar, causing both forms to restore to their original size. When this happens it (not always but most of the time) causes FormA to lose its title bar and border.

Here's a picture of the resulting FormA:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7v7R.jpg
Only when I use any one of the options in the MDI Windows menu (Tile, Cascade, etc.) is the title bar restored.

Why does this happen and what can I do to ensure the MDI gives back the child's title bar after restoring the window?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I found the issue. I'm using Window snapping for Forms within the MDI and it was interfering with initialization. I modified the code and all is well.